# can Instrumentation.redefineClasses trigger VirtualMachine.redefineClasses?

Tags: jvm, instrumentation, hotswap, jdi

If a class has been redefined by Instrumentation.redefineClasses, is there a way to trigger the referenceType be redefined by VirtualMachine.redefineClasses?

Comment: These two methods are both interfaces to the same functionality. It’s not clear what you mean with “to trigger the referenceType be redefined by VirtualMachine.redefineClasses”. What do you expect to happen?

Comment: A java agent is attached to a java program, and debugged by a jdi debugger, sample.class is redefined by java agent using instrumentation.redefineClasses, but the jdi debugger still gets the old version of sample.class(represent by ClassType)

Comment: `VirtualMachine.redefineClasses` is a method that *consumes* bytecode, provided by your debugger application. If you *receive* wrong data, you should name the method that returns wrong data and ask your question as such.